# React: Component state not updating scorekeeper or counter

Tags: reactjs, function, if-statement, components, state

I'm trying to update my component state whenever I click on a right or wrong 'answer' div, out of four choices, to update a scorekeeper and counter. However, when I console log out the scorekeeper and counter values, I always get 0, no matter how many questions I've answered. Why is this happening and how can I update these two pieces of component state?

Here is my code:

```
export default class QuestionCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scorekeeper: 0, 
            counter: 0,
            hideDiv: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleClickCont = this.handleClickCont.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(choice) {
        if(this.state.counter === 4) {
            return console.log('we have four')
        }

        this.handleClickCont(choice)
    }

    handleClickCont(choice) {
        if(choice === this.props.answer) {
            this.setState({scorekeeper: this.state.scorekeeper + 1});
            this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
            console.log('scorekeeper ' + this.state.scorekeeper)
            console.log('counter ' + this.state.counter)
            return this.setState({hideDiv: !this.state.hideDiv});
        } 

        this.setState({scorekeeper: this.state.scorekeeper - 1});
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
        console.log('scorekeeper ' + this.state.scorekeeper);
        console.log(this.state.counter)
        this.setState({hideDiv: !this.state.hideDiv});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{margin: '20px', display: this.state.hideDiv ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
                <div>
                    {this.props.question}
                </div>

                <div style={{
                        margin: '20px', 
                        width: '500px', 
                        display: 'flex', 
                        justifyContent: 'space-around',
                        display: this.state.hideDiv ? 'none' : 'block'
                      }}>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice1)}>
                        {this.props.choice1}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice2)}>
                        {this.props.choice2}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice3)}>
                        {this.props.choice3}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice4)}>
                        {this.props.choice4}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.setState(prevState => {counter: prevState.counter + 1});`. This way you do not lose the current value from the previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state is asynchronous, so that react can do some performance optimisation by batching multiple calls to `setState`. Therefore state changes that rely on previous state values (ie for incrementing a counter) you should use the function version of `setState`
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

You are logging immediately after the calls to `setState`, but as it is async you are logging state that may not have *actually* been set by react yet. You could instead log that in the callback, that is guaranteed to run AFTER state has actually been updated under the surface

As an aside, your code does exactly the same if the answer is correct or not except that it increments rather than decrements the score, so we can DRY that up a bit into a single setState, with a conditional increment value

```
handleClickCont(choice) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
      scorekeeper: prevState.scorekeeper + (choice === this.props.answer ? 1 : -1),
      counter: prevState.counter + 1,
      hideDiv: !prevState.hideDiv
    }),
    () => { // callback, guaranteed to have done your updates by this point
      console.log('scorekeeper ' + this.state.scorekeeper)
      console.log('counter ' + this.state.counter)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. That was a really helpful explanation of what my problem is :). However, I replaced my original handleClickCont function with your code given here, and the first time I answer a question, the scorekeeper and counter pieces of state are correctly updated. However, the second and following times keep console logging 1 at the value for both pieces of state...

Comment: So that sounds like a different problem, where the QuestionCard is a different instance, probably from being dismounted then remounted again with different question props. In that case state counters will start at 0 again, so you can only get to 1 at most. Would have to see what is controlling the questions  and what is rendering `<QuestionCard />` to be sure on the cause of that

Comment: There is nothing in this component to change question in your card when answered, in fact you hide it completely upon answering, which makes me think you simply have 4 side by side seperate QuestionCard instances, in which case they will know nothing about each others state. state is contained in a single instance

Comment: This score/counter state should instead be in the parent, that knows about all question cards, with question card itself having an `onAnswered(correct: boolean): void` property which triggers the state setting

Comment: Yeah that's right, I have 4 side by side separate QuestionCard instances. I moved the score and counter pieces of state to the parent component and it works great now. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

remember this.setState is like the return statement. all statements after setstate might not be executed. As soon as you set set the render method of the component is called unless you specify not to render. still further statements might not be executed.

```
handleClickCont(choice) {
    if(choice === this.props.answer) {
        this.setState({scorekeeper: this.state.scorekeeper + 1,counter: this.state.counter + 1,hideDiv: !this.state.hideDiv});
    } else{

    this.setState({scorekeeper: this.state.scorekeeper - 1,counter: this.state.counter + 1,hideDiv: !this.state.hideDiv});
    }

}
```

also you cant return this.setState. also setState is not always executed when you call it. react might batch it and execute later.